# Calculate Timezone Offset in XSLT Equivalent to oracle TZ_OFFSET function

Tags: xslt, xpath

I needed to calculate time offset from timezones in XSLT which can do the what TZ_Offset function does in Oracle.

For example,  In Oracle

```
Select TZ_Offset('US/Eastern') from DUAL; --returns '-04:00'
```

Is there a function in xslt that can do the same thing ?

Comment: I don't think so. This requires not a calculation, but a lookup from the TZ database.

Comment: I want <timezone>US/Eastern</timezone> is translated into  <timeoffset>-04:00</timeoffset>. Hope that clears up

Comment: Well, the point is that the US/Eastern timezone's offset can be either -4:00 or -5:00, depending on whether daylight saving time is in effect or not. In order to know if it is, you need to lookup the zone's DST rules in the [tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database). XSLT will not do this for you - at least not XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 (it might be possible in XSLT 3.0).

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard XSLT function that does this directly, but you may be able to use format-dateTime for this purpose in XPath 3.0/3.1. This is what the spec says:

> If the $place argument is supplied in the form of an IANA timezone
>   name that is recognized by the implementation, then the date or time
>   being formatted is adjusted to the timezone offset applicable in that
>   timezone. For example, if the xs:dateTime value 2010-02-15T12:00:00Z
>   is formatted with the $place argument set to America/New_York, then
>   the output will be as if the value 2010-02-15T07:00:00-05:00 had been
>   supplied. This adjustment takes daylight savings time into account
>   where possible; if the date in question falls during daylight savings
>   time in New York, then it is adjusted to timezone offset -PT4H rather
>   than -PT5H. Adjustment using daylight savings time is only possible
>   where the value includes a date, and where the date is within the
>   range covered by the timezone database.

So `format-dateTime(current-dateTime(), '[Z00:00]', (), (), 'America/New_York')` should return "-05:00" assuming you're in daylight savings time when you call the function. This should work in Saxon, but I don't know about other implementations.

I haven't come across "US/Eastern" as a timezone name: the Olsen/IANA timezone database generally uses continent/city format to avoid political disputes. It may or may not work depending on the underlying database.